# Assign array length from another another array's length

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to automatically assign a particular array's length to another array so that the user does not have to assign it for second time. The arrays lengths should be equal. I am getting the array length and copying it to an integer, but how do I assign it?

```
public Transform[] pos;
public KeyCode[] key;

void Update()
    {
        int howMany = pos.Length;
        key.Length = howMany; //Does not work
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Length` is a getter property and you cannot set value. You can resize the array using `Array.Resize` method.

```
public Transform[] pos = new Transform[5]; // You must initialize it
public KeyCode[] key;

void Update()
{
    Array.Resize(ref key, pos.Length);
}
```

Comment: Does this help in resizing the array without clearing it?

Comment: Perfect. This is what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: @jay.mila Watch out though - `Array.Resize()` actually allocates a *new* array, copies the elements of the original array to the new array, and then changes the array reference to reference the new array. Any other references to the old array will still be referencing the old array. Normally you would use a `List<T>` for this kind of thing, so that everything referencing that list sees the new list.

Comment: So for example, the output of the following code is "20, 10": `var arr1 = new int[10]; var arr2 = arr1; Array.Resize(ref arr1, 20); Console.WriteLine(arr1.Length + ", " + arr2.Length);`

Answer (score -1):

You didn't initialize `pos` array how do you want to get its length!

**Solution**:
Initialize `key` array with `howMany` variable

Use this code:

```cs
public Transform[] pos = new Transform[5]; // You must initialize it
public KeyCode[] key;

void Update()
{
    int howMany = pos.Length;
    key = new KeyCode[howMany]; // Initialize it with a variable
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I am getting an error ```Property or indexer 'Array.Length' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only```

Comment: @jay.mila Not `key.Length` but `key = new KeyCode[howMany];`